# Short story involving parallel universes and a war between humanity and some dark version of humanity

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, parallel-universe

In this story, as humans travel through closely linked universes, they eventually become distorted and changed. The twist at the end, I believe, was that humans were fighting vastly distorted versions of themselves.

You know, it almost sounds like *[The Way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Way_(novel_series))* series by Greg Bear, but I don't think it was.

Comment: There's a handy guide here; https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/40437
For asking Story ID question that can help prompt you for specific details that can help us figure out the answer.